# What does this SQLite command mean?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am new to using SQLite with python and we have been code in which there is this statement

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)', user)
```

I am not sure what the question marks (?,?) mean, I have tried reading the documentation on sqlite3 website but was not able to get anywhere. Would be a great help if someone can tell me or direct me to the right link.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are placeholders for literal values that can be bound to a prepared SQL statement. Essentially it allows you to supply literal values in the SQL program without putting them into the SQL string. This both prevents SQL injection attacks and improves performance if you're running the same query with different parameter values - the SQL has to be compiled only once.

[Documentation (C API)](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and I think I get your point, just one more thing to clarify ( to make sure I got it rite ) if i have
`user=('abc@gmail.com', 'abc123')`
`c.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)', user)`

the email and password value to go to ?,?

Comment: That's correct. Each element of the list fills in the corresponding placeholder in the query.